# Controlling a 8A DC pump with a PIC

Tags: pic, dc-motor, driver, darlington

I need to activate a 12VDC, 8A diaphragm pump with the output of a PIC16F628 (5VDC, 0.025A maximum). The standard way to do it, as I learned in college, is to saturate a transistor that will drive a relay, that will activate the pump.

Now I am wondering if I could do it with a high current darlington NPN transistor driving the pump directly, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f82vww.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is it possible and/or viable? What are the advantages and disadvantages of this compared to using a transistor driven relay?

Is it easy to find a transistor with the required characteristics? 10A Ice, with gain from 0.025A Ibe to about 20A Ice (needed at pump startup, before stabilizing at 8A Ice). Is there such a device? From the datasheets I find on Google, the higher the Ice, smaller the Hfe, so that I can't drive a high peak current from the PIC...

By the way, what is the voltage drop from base to emitter I must consider in order to dimension R1?

Comment: A darlington is a bad idea here due to its large voltage drop.  At 8 A, it will get toasty.  A FET would be much better.  For example, 15 mOhms would drop 120 mV and dissipate 960 mW.  You may even be able to get away with a TO-220 in free air without a heat sink, depending on worst case ambient temperature around the transistor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have drawn a Darlington, not a transistor. Yes, it's feasible (but far from ideal) to use a Darlington, however it will take more current than your PIC can deliver (so another driver would be required) and will get quite warm (stealing power from the pump). A typical part might require 100-200mA of base current and would drop more than 1 volt (2V maximum).

Instead, I would suggest using a suitable N-channel MOSFET, which can easily handle the current and will run quite cool. You should also **put a diode across the pump** to deal with motor inductance. You will have more choice in MOSFETs if you add a 12V driver for the gate, which could consist of a few small BJTs and resistors.

You might be able to get away with a [AOI508](http://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOI508.pdf) with perhaps a 50 ohm series gate resistor directly driven from the PIC. Put a 10K or so to ground so if the PIC GPIO goes high-Z the transistor won't turn partially on and unsolder itself, burn out, etc.

Comment: With a little research, I found that in MOSFET the gate is insulated from drain and source, so, no current flows through it, why, then, the 50 ohm resistance is needed?

Also, I didn't get the high-Z issue. On high-Z the voltage is undetermined, so, the worst that could happen is turning the pump on, right?

Comment: 1/2 The resistors: It will limit the peak current from the PIC (the gate behaves a bit like a short during switching) and can help from destroying your PIC if the source circuit has inductance (there might be a transient below ground) and it slows the switching a bit which also helps with stray inductance. You can leave it out if you feel lucky.

Comment: 2/2 The *worst* thing that could happen is that the transistor turns half on with the pump stalled, in which case it is dissipating about 60W, which will destroy an non-heatsinked transistor in seconds. Since the gate is insulated it can float around to 1/2-on if it feels like it. You can leave it out if you feel lucky, but during debugging things can happen.